# C++ Created Vector class

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

*void expand()*

This function will double the capacity of the vector. This function should reallocate memory for the dynamically allocated array and update the value of capacity. Be careful to properly handle the case when capacity is 0 before calling expand().

Make sure you don't create a memory leak here.

*void expand(unsigned amount)*

This function will expand the capacity of the vector by the amount passed in. This function should reallocate memory for the dynamically allocated array and update the value of capacity.

Make sure you don't create a memory leak here.

I'm trying to answer complete these functions but I just can't seem to get it working. This is the code that I have so far.

```
void IntVector::expand() {
    cap = cap * 2;
    int *temp = new int[cap];
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        temp[i] = data[i];
    }
    delete [] data;
}

void IntVector::expand(unsigned amount) {
    cap = cap + amount;
    int *temp = new int[cap];
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        temp[i] = data[i];
    }
    delete [] data;
}
```

I also have the private data fields:

-unsigned sz: stores the size of the IntVector (the number of elements currently being used).

-unsigned cap: store the size of the array

-int *data: stores the address of the dynamically-allocated array of integers

I can't seem to figure out the problem.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please post a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example.  As it stands your question is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

add data = temp; after delete[] data;
in fact, you need to do more to take care of failure for allocating memory.

Comment: what more would i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign allocated `temp` to `data`.

And you should check if `amount` is less-equal to `0`, and no need to implement the same logic in two functions.

```
void IntVector::expand() {
    expand(cap);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
}

void IntVector::expand(unsigned amount) {
    if (amount <= 0) return;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    int *temp = new int[cap + amount];
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        temp[i] = data[i];
    }
    cap = cap + amount;
    delete [] data;
    data = temp;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
```

Comment: is that the only thing I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. Failed to assign the `data` member from `temp`:
2. Changing member variables such as `cap` before you are sure you can allocate memory successfully.

For item 2) above, if `new[]` throws an exception, you've corrupted the `cap` member by changing it.

Here are the corrections:

```
void IntVector::expand() {
    int *temp = new int[cap * 2];
    cap *= 2;  // <-- Set this after you've allocated
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        temp[i] = data[i];
    }
    delete [] data;
    data = temp;  // <--- Failed to do this
}

void IntVector::expand(unsigned amount) {
    int *temp = new int[cap + amount];
    cap += amount;  // <-- Set this after you've allocated

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        temp[i] = data[i];
    }
    delete [] data;
    data = temp;  // <--- Failed to do this
}
```